# Write file without system and hdd cache

Tags: c++

How can I write something to a file in C++ without using system cache and drive cache? I just want to write exactly on the hdd regardless all the system cache settings.

Comment: It would probably help if you explained *why* you might want to do this. In other words what are you *really* trying to achieve?

Comment: I heard that some databases perform like this (so they are sure that all data is written to disk) and I'm just curious if that can be done in pure c++.

Comment: @Simon: You heard wrong; databases don't bypass the caches.  Except in rare cases where the DB vendor provides I/O drivers, the RDBMS uses plain old flush.  Also the RDBMS uses several writes and  maintains integrity checks to be sure that *all* writes were consistently flushed to disk.  You might want to update your question with a specific quote or reference on this "bypass cache" theory.

Comment: @ S.Lott: Thanks, I think that it is what I wanted to know.

Comment: It's not what you asked.  Please update your question to reflect what you want to know so we can provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are writing a disk device driver, you can't guarantee that there won't be any cache or processing done with your write.

The C runtime library exposes `fflush(FILE *)` to do this. Windows has `FlushFileBuffers` as well as a flag you can pass to `CreateFile` (`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`) (which itself adds restrictions on what you can do).

An alternative to trying to bypass write caching is to make your data structures resilient to partial failure. For files, one popular technique is to write out the header of the file after the rest of the file is written. Assuming Murphy and not Machiavellian behavior, that should be enough.

Or use the OS provided file replacement or transaction functions (See [ReplaceFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365512(VS.85).aspx) and [Transactional NTFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx) for Windows).

Comment: Actually, that doesn't even protect against Murphy. Common write reordering will cause writes to be reordered in physical order. Even though the header is provided to the OS last, it may hiot disk first if there's enough buffer available. Note that modern disks can do this reordering themselves, outside the OS. (SATA NCQ)

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can pass `O_DIRECT` to [`open(2)`](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/2/open) in order to try to avoid the OS cache, but you don't have the same level of control over the drive cache.

Answer (score 2):

This is highly operating system dependent. On Windows you can specify FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING when you open the file with [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) to disable system caching. You won't get around hard disk caching though.

Comment: If you pass both `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, Windows will tell the disk to bypass its caching too.